# dell-smm-hwmon freezes Alienware m15 r1

Tags: dell, fancontrol, modprobe, alienware

I have tried suggestions such as installing i8kutils and dell-bios-fan-control but it always freezes my laptop if I do

```
sudo modprobe dell-smm-hwmon force=1
```

And if I try to do it without force, it gives out

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'dell_smm_hwmon': No such device
```

Are there any steps I have missed or need to try again?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install i8kutils
sudo modprobe i8k force=1
```

If it works, make `/etc/modprobe.d/i8k.conf` load on booting, by editing:

- `/etc/modprobe.d/i8k.conf`

  ```
  options i8k force=1
  ```
- and `/etc/modules-load.d/i8k.conf`

  ```
  i8k
  ```
- Also disable the i8kmon service if you want to continue controlling the fans with the hardware BIOS handler:

  ```
  sudo systemctl disable i8kmon.service
  ```

Comment: Tried it, after typing `sudo modprobe i8k force=1`, it freezes the entire system.